# Revert transfer if the receiver has more than 1 Token

Tags: erc-721, opensea

Can it be possible to list a collection on Opensea for sell and limit the collection as one Token per user?

I have tried using this `require(balanceOf(msg.sender) == 0, "Each address may only own one Token");` code snippet inside overriding functions of `transferOwnership, approve, transferFrom, safeTransferFrom and mintTo`. And failed!

If could anyone help me on this.

Source: https://github.com/dreygur/Opensea/blob/main/Token-AmiGadhaBolchi.sol

Comment: It would help if you can share the code, or the specific error at least.

Comment: Here is the [Source](https://github.com/dreygur/Opensea/blob/main/Token-AmiGadhaBolchi.sol)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest solution is overriding `_beforeTokenTransfer`, since it's called before any possible increment in balance.

```js
    function _beforeTokenTransfer(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 tokenId
    ) internal virtual override {
        if (to != address(0) && from != address(0)) {
            require(balanceOf(to) == 0, "Each address may only own one Token");
        }
    }
```

This way the recipient needs to have zero tokens, otherwise the transaction reverts.

The clause `to != address(0)` is needed otherwise `balanceOf` reverts when it tries to burn tokens. The `from != address(0)` to allow multiple minting to the same address.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But adding this function reverts even the Contract deploy

Comment: Ok, cause in the constructor you are minting more than 1 token for yourself. I added some logic to prevent reverts during minting.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Now I get it.